# scrolling UIScrollView from edge of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an iPad app that uses a horizontal scroll view with a bunch of controls as subviews. The user has to be able to use all the controls inside the scrollview and only scroll the view if they deliberately drag a finger from outside the left or right edge of the screen.

I've implemented this by putting this code in the UIScrollView's pointInside:forEvent: method.

```
- (BOOL) pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // scroll the view if the user's finger has dragged from off-screen. 
    [self setScrollEnabled:(point.x - self.contentOffset.x < 9 || point.x > self.contentOffset.x + self.frame.size.width - 9) ||
 self.isDecelerating];

    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}
```

When the iPad is in `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` (home button on right side of the screen), I can drag my fingers from outside the right side or left side inwards and the `UIScrollView` scrolls as intended. However, when I switch orientations, dragging from the left side (home button) scrolls fine while the right side (near the camera) only works about 50% of the time.

I've tried extending the frame of the scroll view to be slightly outside the bounds of the screen, but I still only have problems with this type of gesture on that one side on `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`. Ideas?

**EDIT:** I added two `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizers` for both sides of the screen — the gesture is more responsive now, but dragging from the right side of the screen while the home button is on the left is still sketchy at best. I have no idea why this would be happening for just that interface orientation.

Comment: why don't you use UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer ?

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue with UIInterfaceOrientationLeft. Any ideas?